# Flask database migrations on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, flask-migrate, flask-script

With my app I am using flask-script and flask-migrate for database migrations, everything works locally.  When, I run

```
heroku run python manage.py db init
```

It creates this output:

```
Running python manage.py db init on ⬢ fpds-scheduler... up, run.1290 (Free)
  Creating directory /app/migrations ... done
  Creating directory /app/migrations/versions ... done
  Generating /app/migrations/README ... done
  Generating /app/migrations/script.py.mako ... done
  Generating /app/migrations/alembic.ini ... done
  Generating /app/migrations/env.py ... done
  Please edit configuration/connection/logging settings in '/app/migrations/alembic.ini' before
  proceeding.
```

But when I run `heroku run python manage.py db migrate` I get an error

```
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Path doesn't exist: 'migrations'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.
```

When I run `heroku run bash` and look at my directory I can see that there is no `migrations` folder...

I have tried running giving the command `--app fpds-scheduler` but that doesn't seem to be working either.

I am not sure what is going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You **must not** create the migrations on Heroku itself. The filesystem is ephemeral and anything written programatically will be lost between invocations.

You need to create the migrations locally, commit them to version control, deploy, and only then run them on Heroku.

Comment: So to be clear, you create you migrations folder locally and then do migrations/upgrades on heroku?

Comment: yeah, do `heroku local db init` then commit the result.

Comment: You actually want to do `flask db init` and `flask db migrate` locally. Commit the results to your git repo. Then on Heroku, you only do the `heroku run flask db upgrade`.